# how do I generate 2 random prime numbers that when multiplied, yield a number with X bits? (X given as argument))

Tags: math, primes, bit

I lack the math skills to make this function.

basically, i want to return 2 random prime numbers that when multiplied, yield a number of bits X given as argument.

for example:

if I say my X is 3 then a possible solution would be:
p = 2 and q = 3 becouse 2 * 3 = 6 (110 has 3 bits).

Comment: The meaning of "random" is not very clear here.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to implement RSA?

Comment: If p has x bits and q has y bits, then p * q has x + y bits.

Answer (score 3):

A problem with this statement is that it starts by asking for two "random" prime numbers. Without any explicit statement of the distribution of the required random primes, we are already stuck. (This is the beginning of a classic paradox, where we are asked to generate a "random" integer.)

But suppose that we change the statement to finding any two arbitrary primes, that yield the desired product with a given number of bits x. The answer is trivial.

The set of numbers that have exactly x bits in their binary representation is the half open set of integers [2^(x-1),2^x-1].

1. Choose an arbitrary prime number that is less than or equal to (2^x-1)/2. Call it p1.
2. Next, choose a second prime number that lies in the interval (2^(x-1)/p1,(2^x-1)/p1). Call it p2.

It must be true that p1*p2 will be in the desired interval.

For example, given x = 10, so the product must lie in the interval [512,1023], the set of integers with exactly 10 bits. (Note, there are apparently 147 such numbers in that interval, with exactly two prime factors.)

Step 1:

Choose p1 as any prime no larger than 1023/2 = 511.5. I'll pick p1 = 137. Then the second prime factor must be a prime that lies in the interval

```
[512 1023]/137
ans =
    3.7372    7.4672
```

thus either 5 or 7.

```
dec2bin(137*[5 7])
ans =
    1010101101
    1110111111
```

Comment: Yes. The distribution is important. :) The whole answer is formally exact, but: If both distributions will be linear then the probability that the second prime will be `2` is more than 0.7. If accidentally PO forgot to write that the product should not be easy factorized, then the second answer of Thomas can be more useful for him :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of bits, you can generate a number 2^(x-2) < x < 2^(x-1).  Then take the square root and find the closest primes on either side of it.  Multiplying them together will, in most cases, get you a number in the correct range.  If it's too high, you can take the two primes directly on the lower side of it.

pseudocode:

```
x = bits
primelist[] = makeprimelist()
rand = randnum between 2^(x-2) and 2^(x-1)
n = findposition(primelist, rand)
do
    result = primelist[n]*primelist[n+1]
    n--
while result > 2^(x-1)
```

Note that numbers generated this way will allways have '1' as the highest significant bit, so would be possible to generate a number of x-1 bits and just tack the 1 onto the end.